# Can you merge elements of Pandas dataframes into tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

If you have two Pandas dataframes in Python with identical axes, is there a function to merge the elements as tuples so that they maintain their positions? If there is a better way to combine these dataframes without duplicating the number of indices or columns, that works as well.

Expected logic:

[image: Image of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: Please include reproducible data that can be copy pasted instead of images and also include your attempts in solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you're looking for seems like "zip".  That is, match elements of two sequences together into a sequence of tuples.  If you look at each column in your dataframes and zip them together you will have a result that is a list of lists of tuples - what you want to be in your result dataframe.  You can then construct a dataframe with the same columns and index out of that data.  In code, that looks like this:

```
data = [list(zip(df1[col], df2[col])) for col in df1]
pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1,2,3], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure pandas:

```
(pd.concat([df1,df2])
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=[0,1])
   .apply(tuple)
   .unstack()
 )
```

Output:

```
        A        B
0  (1, 7)  (4, 10)
1  (2, 8)  (5, 11)
2  (3, 9)  (6, 12)
```

Input:

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[7,8,9],"B":[10,11,12]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.compare(df2).groupby(level=0,axis=1).apply(lambda dd:dd.agg(tuple,axis=1))
```

Output:

```
        A        B
0  (1, 7)  (4, 10)
1  (2, 8)  (5, 11)
2  (3, 9)  (6, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use something like this to achieve what you want.

`df3 = pd.DataFrame({x: zip(df1[x], df2[x]) for x in df1.columns})`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,2,3], "B":[4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [7,8,9], "B":[10,11,12]})

def add_dfs(df1, df2):
    for col in df1.columns:
        df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: (x,))
    for col in df2.columns:
        df2[col] = df2[col].apply(lambda x: (x,))
    df = df1 + df2 # using + operator , satisfies answer technically
    return df

df = add_dfs(df1, df2)
```